# Pass Controller and action in url

Tags: php, routes, symfony

Is it any way to generate url which contain controller and action in it?

I need to have urls with something like this:

```
/admin/{controller}/{action}/{some other things}
```

So when I call url: `/admin/pages/add` i will call: `AdminBundle:Pages:add` 
So I don't need to add in `routing.yml` entries for all controllers and action combinations in my admin panel, such as:

```
/admin/page/add
/admin/page/edit/1
/admin/user/add
etc.
```

I know that, when i add on routing something like this:

```
admin_default:
    path:     /{_controller}
    defaults: { _controller: AdminBundle:Page:index }
```

url such as `/admin/AdminBundle:Page:add` will work, but it's not what I expect.

Comment: To do this right you would probably have to override the ControllerResolver.  There are some examples out there.  Lot of work for saving a bit of copy/paste/edit.  You already need to create the controllers and the methods.  Is it really worth the time to add more magic to the system?

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of this feature in the [EsayAdminBudle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Controller/AdminController.php#L106):

```
$action = $request->query->get('action', 'list');
```

But the code can be complicated as there is a lot of abstraction.

Comment: It is not clear (to me) how your posted code will actually kickoff a controller/action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, @Route and associates it to an Action

```
 /**
 * @Route("/home/list/parameter", name="home-list-parameter")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
  public function getParametersAction() {
  ...
```

http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/routing.html

Comment: How does this address the question?